# Quickblox Custom Object Android:Or Operator

Tags: android, object, quickblox

I have 5 fields in a custom object and I need to create a request builder that checks if any of these 5 fields contain a specific string. I tried this:

```
QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();
    customObjectRequestBuilder.eq("tag1", searchTerm);
    customObjectRequestBuilder.eq("tag2", searchTerm);
    customObjectRequestBuilder.eq("tag3", searchTerm);
    customObjectRequestBuilder.eq("tag4", searchTerm);
    customObjectRequestBuilder.eq("tag5", searchTerm);
```

But, of course, this will only return records where all 5 fields equal the search term.

I need to know to know how to build a request that returns records in which at least one of the fields equal the search term.

A code example would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();
    customObjectRequestBuilder.or("tag1[or]=" + searchTerm + "&tag2[or]=" + searchTerm + "&tag3[or]=" + searchTerm + "&tag4[or]=" + searchTerm + "&tag5[or]=" + searchTerm);
```